# FPC fpjson mangles emojis in strings

Tags: json, pascal, freepascal

I am having trouble sending emojis in strings using fpjson:

```pascal
program Demo;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses fphttpserver, httpdefs, fpjson;

const wave = '';

type
  THandler = class
    procedure HandleRequest(Sender: TObject; var ARequest: TFPHTTPConnectionRequest; var AResponse: TFPHTTPConnectionResponse);
    end;

procedure THandler.HandleRequest(Sender: TObject; var ARequest: TFPHTTPConnectionRequest; var AResponse: TFPHTTPConnectionResponse);
var AJSONString: TJSONString;
begin
  AJSONString := TJSONString.Create(wave);

  AResponse.ContentType := 'application/json';
  AResponse.Contents.Text := AJSONString.AsJSON;
end;

var
  httpServer: TFPHttpServer;
  Handler: THandler;
begin
  try
    httpServer := TFPHttpServer.Create(nil);
    httpServer.Active := false;
    httpServer.Port := 3000;
    httpServer.OnRequest := @Handler.HandleRequest;
    httpServer.Active := true;
  finally
    httpServer.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Sending any request on port 3000 results in some mangled unicode:

[image: Request to http://localhost:3000 showing a unicode unknown character followed by three questionmarks as response]

Replacing the `AJSONString.AsJSON` with just `''` however, results in a perfectly fine result:

[image: Request to http://localhost:3000 showing the unicode wave emoji as response]

This leads me to believe that somewhere within fpjson the character is mangled and worked my way to the `StringToJSONString` function which produces the same behaviour.

How can I work my way around this and ensure that emojis in my JSON body are sent as expected? I have also tried just sending Unicdode escapes like `\u270b` for a raised hand but that resulted in `\\u270b` as response because the backslash is doubled as escape and the whole thing ended up ignored on the client of the API.

Comment: Target?  On Windows 1-byte strings are  not unicode by default in FPC, but can be made to do so. *nix is generally utf8

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort The endgoal is to compile and run the code in a ubuntu docker container

Comment: Make sure your editor saves as utf8 then.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort I am pretty sure it does since sending the emoji as string directly works just as expected; it seems like fpjson messes with the encoding somehow or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit grumpy over this because I was certain I tried it but adding a codepage directive to the top was all that was missing:

```pascal
program Demo;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
{$codepage utf8}
```

After this, emojis behave as expected even in `StringToJSONString`!